# QML - Buttons in motion

Tags: qml

На QML нужно сделать кнопки с поведением как показано у Гугла в [документации](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons.html#buttons-flat-raised-buttons) раздел "Buttons in motion".

Подскажите, может где есть готовые или похожие?
В первую очередь интересует реализация анимации, конечно.

Comment: а в чём проблема? рисуете кружок и анимируете его радиус

Answer (score 0):

В QML есть плагин с [темой Material](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html). Она деляет почти все контролы похожими на те что в спецификации гугла. Радиус разбегается при нажатии ;)